# Echo name from custom field wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a while loop that fetch me all the posts in a specific category,
Now I have add the custom values but the problem is that it only echo out the value of the custom field and not the name,

The function i use for printing out the value is

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    the_meta();
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Now I have tried to echo out the `get_post_custom_keys($post->ID);` 
but that only gives me the output `"array"`

I also tried a foreach loop, but it only gave me the name of the last post

```
$meta_key_used = get_post_custom_keys($post->ID); 
foreach ($meta_key_used as $meta_key) {
echo $meta_key;
```

Any ideas on how to print out the name of the custom field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have all the post IDs that you want to call it for, then you could do this...

```
$post_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  // for example

foreach ($post_ids as $post_id)
{
  $meta_key_used = get_post_custom_keys($post_id); 

  echo "Custom key names for post " . $post_id . "...<br />";

  foreach ($meta_key_used as $array_key => $meta_key_name)
  {
    $namet = trim($meta_key_name);

    if ('_' == $namet{0})    // ignore wp internal keys
      continue; 

    echo $array_key . " => " . $meta_key_name . "<br />";
  }
}
```

This excludes any Wordpress internal keys where the value begins with an underscore.

Comment: Hmm I don't know if it this im looking for, this only gives me an number, i would like to embed the function in the while loop so I can use the name field of the custom fields as link.

Comment: OK @Dymond what do you see when we echo the value as well? I have updated my answer to do this.

Comment: Yes, now its actually echoing out the value name, but only from the last post, is it possible to use this inside the while loop ?

Comment: @Dymond yes, if you have all the post IDs that you want to loop through. Updated answer again.

Comment: It worked!! thank you. been hassling with this for a while now :)
really really nice solution also!